# Ruby on Rails form path for a third model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, networking, network-programming

I'm working on a map for the network in my building. I have the separate floor models working, which list each switch when you click on the show method. Then I would like to have it so you can click on each switch to see the jack numbers on each switch port. I have the view for the switch working thanks to another question I've asked, but now I'm stuck trying to show the jacks in that same show. Here is my partial for the jacks (app/views/jacks/_jacks.html.erb):

```
<%= form_for <WhatDoIPutHere?> do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :number %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :number %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Now I know I need to run a rake routes to figure out the path.
Here is my rake routes result:

```
floor_switch_jacks GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks(.:format)         jacks#index
                   POST   /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks(.:format)          jacks#create
new_floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/new(.:format)      jacks#new
edit_floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id/edit(.:format) jacks#edit
 floor_switch_jack GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#show
                   PUT    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#update
                   DELETE /floors/:floor_id/switches/:switch_id/jacks/:id(.:format)      jacks#destroy
    floor_switches GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches(.:format)                           switches#index
                   POST   /floors/:floor_id/switches(.:format)                           switches#create
  new_floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/new(.:format)                       switches#new
 edit_floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id/edit(.:format)                  switches#edit
      floor_switch GET    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#show
                   PUT    /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#update
                   DELETE /floors/:floor_id/switches/:id(.:format)                       switches#destroy
            floors GET    /floors(.:format)                                              floors#index
                   POST   /floors(.:format)                                              floors#create
         new_floor GET    /floors/new(.:format)                                          floors#new
        edit_floor GET    /floors/:id/edit(.:format)                                     floors#edit
             floor GET    /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#show
                   PUT    /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#update
                   DELETE /floors/:id(.:format)                                          floors#destroy
        home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                                          home#index
              root        /                                                              home#index
```

My question is how do I read the rake routes to find the proper syntax for the form_for line? I had this same problem getting my switch view to work in the first place. If this is an easy question and there is a guide out there feel free to just send me to that instead. I can't seem to find one specific to to this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT:

```
class JacksController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @switch = Switch.find(params[:switch_id])
    @jack = @switch.jacks.create(params[:jack])
    redirect_to switch_path(@switch)
  end

  def destroy
    @switch = Switch.find(params[:switch_id])
    @jack = @switch.jacks.find(params[:id])
    @jack.destroy
    redirect_to switch_path(@switch)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have nested forms for your nested models.

```
form_for @floor do |f|
  f.fields_for :switches do |g|
    g.fields_for :jacks do |h|
      h.label :number
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to work, but now when I try to create a new jack (when I hit the submit button from the switch view) it saves the floor and doesn't do anything with Jacks. Could this be in my jack controller? I'll include both my new code and my jack controller.

Comment: You need to make sure that your models `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the appropriate sub-models

Comment: Oh, sorry, in the models themselves, not the view. My bad. I'll try that out.

Comment: I seem to have everything working now! I was over-thinking the form_for syntax in the jack form as well. I'm about to post another question regarding the jack's create method now though because I can't quite get that to work either (even though I thought it would be one deeper than the one I used for switches, it did not work). If you could help me on that as well I would be grateful!

Comment: If you accept this answer, then others will be helped as well.

Comment: Hey, instead of nesting more than once I'm doing only single nests. It's working out much better. Thank you for your help, though.